# CSS Floats in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, css-float

In my tabs menu, I'm trying to put in css floats. But every time I put in a image with the id from the css stylesheet, it's not inside the tabs?

This is my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="units.html">Units</a></li>
    <li><a href="student work.html">Student Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="survey.html">Survey</a></li>
    <li><a href="excursions.html">Excursions</a></li>
    <li><a href="vc.html">Vocational Certificate</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante.</p>
    <img id="div1" src="images/The_Best_Dog_Breeds_18262_10912.jpg" width="800" height="473" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
#div1 {float: right;
      clear: both;
}

#div2  {float: left;
       clear: both;
}
```

The annoying thing is, I have to have the css in a separate stylesheet, so I can't put any css in my html document.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it seems that you first do:

```
float: right;
```

And after that, you clear that setting immediately with:

```
clear: both;
```

What happens if you try swapping the two of them?:

```
#div1 {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}

#div2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```